# Difference between pandas.Series.str.match and pandas.Series.str.contains

Tags: python, pandas

What's the difference between `pandas.Series.str.contains` and `pandas.Series.str.match`? Why is the case below?

```py
s1 = pd.Series(['house and parrot'])
s1.str.contains(r"\bparrot\b", case=False)
```

I got `True`, but when I do

```py
s1.str.match(r"\bparrot\b", case=False)
```

I got `False`. Why is the case?

Comment: s1.str.fullmatch might also be interesting

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation for [`str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) states:

> Test if pattern or regex is contained within a string of a Series or
> Index.

The documentation for [`str.match()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) states:

> Determine if each string matches a regular expression.

The difference in these two methods is that `str.contains()` uses: `re.search`, while `str.match()` uses `re.match`.

As per documentation of [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.match)

> If zero or more characters at the **beginning** of string match the
> regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object.
> Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this
> is different from a zero-length match.

So `parrot` does not match the first character of the string so your expression returns False. `House` does match the first character so it finds `house` and returns true.

Comment: "house" won't match the entire string, but `s1.str.match(r"\bhouse\b", case=False)` returns `True`. Why?

Comment: Thanks. I should have checked re.match() document.