# Filtering by using queries from input

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to search within more columns some words selected by input. It could be just one word or more than one (so a list of words). 
This is how my dataset looks like:

```
Text1                                 Text2
Include details about your goal...    Include any error messages...
Describe expected and actual results  Help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems: 4.5 points
```

Let us say that, for example, I would like to select only elements that contain goal or error, words that I added manually by using input:

I should have:

```
Text1                                 Text2
Include details about your goal...    Include any error messages...
```

I could also create a new column that add a boolean value in case there is a match with my search/filter request for one/both columns/terms (`True`) or none (`False`).

I have tried as follows:

```
def matcher(x):
    for i in list_to_search:
        if i.lower() in x.lower():
            return i
    else:
        return np.nan

list_to_search = [] 
while True:
    query = input("Enter your query: ")
    list_to_search.append(query)
    print(list_to_search)

print(list_to_search)

df['Match'] = df['Text1'].apply(matcher)
```

However the code above run forever because of `while True` condition. From the example above, I would like only to search for `goals` **or** `errors`, but I would have also searched for `goals` **and** `errors`. And I would also be interested in looking for possible consecutive words (for example `4.5 points`). Finally, I do not know how to check for multiple columns (in the code above I am looking only for matching in column `Text1`, not in `Text1` and/or `Text2`).

I hope you can help me. Thanks

UPDATE: I think I have fixed the issue with the while loop:

```
list_to_search = [] 

def matcher(x):
    for i in list_to_search:
        if i.lower() in x.lower():
            return i
    else:
        return np.nan

while True:
    query = input("Enter your query: ")
    if query!='-f':
        list_to_search.append(query)
        print(list_to_search)

    if query=='-f':
        break
print(list_to_search)

df['Match'] = df['Text1'].apply(matcher)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use [`Series.str.lower()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) and [`Series.str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) (**`regex=True`** by default)

```
m = df['Text1'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(mylist))
```

then you can filter `Text1` column:

```
df.loc[m,'Text1']
```

I think we have to try avoid use apply here, you can see [`it`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code) about when use apply in your code

if you want look for words in a list of columns you can use:

```
my_columns = ['Text1', 'Text2']

m = (df[my_columns].stack(dropna=False).str.lower()
                   .str.contains('|'.join(mylist))
                   .unstack())

df.where(m)
```

We can also iter through columns:

```
for name_colum, column_serie in df[my_columns].items():
    m = (column_serie.str.lower()
                     .str.contains('|'.join(mylist)))
   print(column_serie[m])
```

**Here is an example:**

```
l = ['a','b']
mask = '|'.join(l)
s = pd.Series(['a','b','c'])
s.str.lower().str.contains(mask)
```

Finally you can also see:

[`Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) instead `Series.str.contains`

[`difference between pandas series str match and pandas series str contains`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57875099/difference-between-pandas-series-str-match-and-pandas-series-str-contains)

Comment: Using the first line of code for `m` I am getting the following error: `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable` . I do not know if the issue comes from the input function

Comment: sorry I forget: *`()`* in `'|'.join([list of words])`, example:  `'|'.join([l'hello', 'home', 'make'])`

Comment: this one: `m = df['Text1'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join([my_list]))`. I used a fake list: `my_list=['ball','bag']` as I do not know if the way to add items to search is correct or not

Comment: Sorry, I understand that my explanation was not clear. THe correct way is `m = df['Text1'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(['ball', 'bag']))`

Comment: Changing in: `m = df['Titles'].str.lower().str.contains('|'.join(my_list))` I have not got any error. It should work. May I ask you f it is ok to use my input list?

Comment: I think you can perfectly use an input list that is loaded with a while loop just like you do in your code. This code works even when the list only has a single word.

Comment: Also I would use : `while query != '-f':` , 
so you don't need use any clause `if` inside `while loop `
and you don't need `break`

Comment: By using  `m = (df[my_columns].stack(dropna=False).str.lower()
                   .str.contains('|'.join(mylist))
                   .unstack())`
 I got the following error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`. Do you know why?

Comment: Are you using MultiIndex in columns? DataFrame.stack is used here in order to convert the dataframe in a stacked series and then we can use series.str.contains... so I think you could have a Multicolumns Dataframe, check isinstance(df.stack(), pd.Series)